# alert do javascript - desabilitar "Bloquear janelas de confirmação desta página?"

Tags: javascript

Quando usamos o alert por várias vezes abre um checkbox onde o usuário tem a opção de desativar o alert, existe alguma forma de desabilitar esse recurso? ( **Não mostrar o checkbox nunca** )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Altere as configurações do navegador. Veja como http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2172671&p=10737317#p10737317

Comment: @HeloisaRocha tentei configurar o **dom.successive_dialog_time_limit** mas não resolveu

Answer (score 4):

Esse comportamento é do navegador e não do JavaScript em si. Funciona como se fosse uma ferramenta de segurança do navegador, para desabilitar isso (se possível) tem que ser feito nas configurações do navegador. No caso de um site já em produção, dificilmente isso seria possível bloquear esse tipo de mensagem para todos os usuários.

Se você está usando isso para debugar, utilize console.log().

Answer (score 3):

Você pode combinar JavaScript, HTML e CSS para mostrar alertas muito mais bonitos e sofisticados (por exemplo, janelas modais) do que o `alert` default do browser.

O navegador não tem controle sobre esses alertas customizados e não dá ao usuário a opção de bloqueá-los.

Uma biblioteca que você pode usar para isso é a [VEX](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/). Você pode vê-la em funcionamento executando o exemplo de código abaixo:

```js
vex.defaultOptions.className = 'vex-theme-os';

function mostreFeedback(mensagem) {
  jQuery("#feedback").attr('value', mensagem);
}

function confirmacao() {
  vex.dialog.confirm({
    message: 'Você tem certeza que deseja fazer isso?',
    callback: function(resultado) {
      if (resultado) {
        mostreFeedback("Ação confirmada com sucesso");
      } else {
        mostreFeedback("Ação cancelada");
      }
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/2.3.3/css/vex-theme-os.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/2.3.3/css/vex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/2.3.3/js/vex.combined.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Confirmação" onclick="confirmacao()" />

<br />
<br />

<input id="feedback" type="text" readonly style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: UlyssesAlves Nossa essa biblioteca e show!! Me ajudou muito aqui e apesar de ser simples da para fazer muitas coisas com ela.

Comment: Que bom que foi útil, @WillianCoqueiro. Também achei ela uma biblioteca bem útil. Qualquer dúvida sobre como usar pode perguntar que a gente tenta esclarescer. []s

Comment: Já atribui ela aqui a muitas coisas aqui. Mais sabe me dizer se consigo ela da o alert e fechar após alguns segundos?

Comment: Achei uma solução, estou avisando para não perder seu tempo: `setTimeout(function(){vex.close()()}, 3000);`. Ele fecha a caixa anterior. Pena que fecha sem esmaecer. Vou procurar na biblioteca para ver se consigo alterar.

Comment: Hoje tá bem corrido aqui, inclusive vi seu comentário por que to pesquisando no stackoverflow sobre um problema que tá ocorrendo numa aplicação aqui. Dei uma olhada rápida na API do vex, única coisa que vi lá foi a opção `closeClassName` e o plugin `vex-dialog` (https://github.com/bbatliner/vex-dialog). Quando eu tiver mais tempo olho com mais calma pra tentar descobrir como fazer isso também. Se você achar antes compartilha com a gente. Valeu.

Comment: Então vex.close() fecha a caixa anterior. Mais fecha de imediato, e não esmaecendo. Vex.closeall() fecha todas.

Comment: Consegui desta forma também, que e como acontece quando clicamos em OK: `setTimeout(function(){$('.vex-dialog-button-primary.vex-dialog-button.vex-first').submit();}, 5000);` Já para clicar em Cancel se usa: `setTimeout(function(){$('.vex-dialog-button-secondary.vex-dialog-button.vex-last').submit();}, 5000);`

Comment: Outra coisa que achei interessante que da para redefinir o nome dos botões antes de cada janela. `vex.dialog.buttons.YES.text = 'Sim'
vex.dialog.buttons.NO.text = 'Não'`